# Setup -match statement

Tags: parsing, powershell, match

I'm trying to setup a -match statement based on a number of conditions.

These are my conditions:
Lines that contain a holiday date follow these rules.

- They contain the text "title", followed by
- one or more of any character, followed by
- the text "when: " (note the trailing space), followed by
- three "word" characters and a space, followed by
- the date in "dd mmm yyyy" format (i.e., "31 Dec 2012”), followed by
- a character that is not a space, "word" or "digit"

The characters that match the underlined bullet point are the ones that need to be
extracted, converted to a [datetime] value, and returned to the caller.

A sample of the data is based on holiday dates.  The Focus line is in BOLD.

> <br />Event Status: confirmedhttp://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=MjAxNTAyMTRfNjBvMzBkcjQ2c28zMGMxZzYwbzMwZHI0Y28gdXNhX19lbkBo' title='alternate'/>http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/usa__en%40holiday.calendar.google.com/public/basic/20150214_60o30dr46so30c1g60o30dr4co'/>Holidays in United Stateshttp://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/usa__en%40holiday.calendar.google.com/public/basic/20140214_60o30dr46so30c1g60o30dr4ck2014-03-24T19:02:40.000Z2014-03-24T19:02:40.000Zhttp://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind' term='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#event'/>**Valentine&#39;s DayWhen: Fri 14 Feb 2014<br>**<br>Who: Holidays in United States

This is what I have so far:
`'title.*when:\s+(\w{1,3})\s(?<Date>)(?\S\W\D)'`

I get this error:

`parsing "title.*when:\s+(\w{1,3})\s(?<Date>)(?\S\W\D)" - Unrecognized grouping 
construct.
At D:\test.ps1:9 char:8
+         if ( $_ -match 'title.*when:\s+(\w{1,3})\s(?<Date>)(?\S\W\D)')
+              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException`

What have I done wrong?

Comment: You are missing the part of the regular expression that matches the actual date.

Comment: should I replace (?<Date>?) with `\d{1,2}\s\w{1,3}\s\d{1,4}`?

Comment: Yes, that would do the trick. The `(?<Date>...)` construct is called a "named group". It just provides a way of retrieving the matched text. You could do this for instance: `(?<Date>\d{1,2}\s\w{1,3}\s\d{1,4})`, and then you could retrieve the matched date from the "Date" group. Do some reading on "named groups".

Comment: Thank you.  It's worked out for me - was able to perform what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you went off the rails here:

```
(?<Date>)(?\S\W\D)
```

A named group construct is (? followed by the regex and the closing paren:

```
(?<Date>?\S\W\D)
```

Comment: I don't see how that could possible match on a date like "14 Feb 2014". It's not even a valid regular expression.